# How to see and change swapfile/hibernate settings through GUI?

Tags: suspend, swap, hibernate, settings, system-settings

When Ubuntu `Desktop` **22:04** is installed, while the process itself appears a screen with the some options about swapfile, hibernate .. and perhaps more if my memory does not fail me.

Once completed the installation process, through **GUI** where is possible see that settings? I mean if was selected swapfile or hibernate. And of course, if is possible changed it. I looked for at `Settings` and seems does not exist.